# Css двойной текст

Tags: css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день! подскажите какие есть варианты реализации данного текста, картинкой вставлять не хотелось бы.

UPDATE:
в мобильной версии нужно наложить этот же текст, проблема в том, что бэкграуд перекрывает картинку.
https://codepen.io/shonov/pen/ydvzWx

```
.header
  .header__content
    .header__row
        .header__column
            .header__offer
                .header__text.header__text--back Mid&nbsp;
                    span.header__text--span August
                    br
                    | Official
                .header__text.header__text--front Mid&nbsp;
                    span.header__text--span August
                    br
                    | Official
        .header__column.header__column--images
        img(src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//70/237/70237004_PICT2111_0.jpg").header__item


$main-color: #fff;
$custom-color: #ff5564;

.header {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  &__content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
  }

  &__row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;

    &--with-form {
      margin-top: -63px;
    }
  }

    &__column {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;

    &--for-padding {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    &--offer {
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }

    &--images {
      margin-top: -165px;
      max-height: 336px;
    }
  }

  &__text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: "Gotham Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: rgb(29, 29, 27);
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;

    &--back {
      height: 215px;
      line-height: 110px;
    }

    &--front {
      height: 110px;
      line-height: 55px;
      background: $main-color;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }

    &--span {
      color: #ff5564;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: скрипт и цсс, по другому ума не приложу даже (ну кроме как картинки)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.text-double {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px; /* Фиксируем высоту родителя */
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #171714;
  position: relative;
}

.text-double span {color: #ff5465;}

.text-double > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /* тут общие стили, суть в том, что элементы по высоте находятся в центре родителя */
}

.text-double .text-back {
  height: 200px; /* Блок "заднего" текста будет высотой во весь родитель */
  line-height: 100px; /* Т.е. строчек две => межстроный интервал будет равен *высоте блока* / *на кол-во строчек* */
}

.text-double .text-front {
  height: 100px; /* Тут аналогично заднему блоку, только он будет меньше по высоте, из-за этого сложится эффект нужный вам. */
  line-height: 50px; /* Аналогично предыдущему. */
  background: #f5f5f5; /* Ну и цвет фона тот, что "за" родителем. Увы, если этот эффект будет на "разноцветном" месте, то уже реализовать проще на SVG */
}
```

```html
<div class="text-double">
  <div class="text-back">MID <span>AUGUST</span> OFICIAL</div>
  <div class="text-front">MID <span>AUGUST</span> OFICIAL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, но было бы лучше, если бы были хоть минимальные комментарии кода.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, если ты хоть чуть-чуть знаешь css, то объяснять тут нечего)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 ну а зачем люди спрашивают?  Ведь css все немного знают :)  svg все немного знают, но тем не менее раз за разом приходиться объяснять Код без комментариев выглядит либо, как демонстрация своих возможностей, либо он чужой.  Извини, это не относится к тебе. Просто мысли вслух...

Comment: @ВиталийШонов, всё таких Alexandr_TT прав, по этому добавил комментарии)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, помоги плиз с моб. версией